# Which column is generating this error "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')."?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have big dataframe with thousands of columns

I am trying to fit a predictive model

but while doing that I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-13-50009d5c9ae8>", line 1, in <module>
     mdl.fit(X_train, y_train)

   File "C:\Users\am479\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py",line 458, in fit
     y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)

   File "C:\Users\am479\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 756, in check_X_y
     estimator=estimator)

   File "C:\Users\am479\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 573, in check_array
     allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')

    File "C:\Users\am479\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 56, in _assert_all_finite
     raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype)) 
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

ok I get it there is a NaN in a numeric field which it does not allow.

my problem is how to know which column has this error

the error message does not say much.

Comment: `df.isnull().any()`

Comment: @pythonic833 this will tell me if it has null or not [returns true or false] , which I already know because of the error

Comment: this will return a series with the column names as index and shows true or false for each index

Comment: @pythonic833 Thanks, it really helps.  but still doesn't tell which one is causing the error

Comment: @pythonic833 getting this error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 432), indices imply (137060, 6130)

Comment: Not to fix your problem, but if you have such a big data, you can consider to drop the rows with nan with `df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')` and see if 1 - you still have a lot of data and 2 - you still have the same error?

Comment: and have you seem [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32)?

Comment: Thanks @pythonic833 &  Ben.T i will use both of your comments to fix this . first i will find columns that have null true using df.isnull().any() then i will remove nulls using df.dropna(axis=0, how='columnName')